# Multiprocessing big CSV's does not return expected amount of rows

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to help someone out with something. I'm by no means an expert programmer but what I'm trying to do is calculate a value from one CSV based on the year and ID from another CSV. The program works as I intended to if I statically put a smaller sample size for time and testing purposes (amount_of_reviews works with a 180mb CSV). But when I want it to work ALL the data I seem to be missing about 2000 from the expected 20245 results (one of the threads fails perhaps?). I am using multiprocessing to reduce the time the program takes to run. I will just go ahead and post all my code here and I hope maybe someone with experience can spot my mistake(s).

```
import csv
import os
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Array, Value
import datetime
from ctypes import c_char_p

print (datetime.datetime.now())

with open('D:/temp/listings.csv', encoding="utf8") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    f.seek(0)

    idSet = set()
    for row in reader:
        idSet.add(row[0])

idList = list(idSet)
idList = sorted(idList)
listings = []

def amount_of_reviews_2019(id):
    total = 0
    with open('D:/temp/reviews.csv', encoding="utf8") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        f.seek(0)
        next(reader)

        for row in reader:
            if int(row[2][:4]) >= 2019 and row[0] == id:
                total = total + 1
        return total


def calc(id):
    with open('D:/temp/listings.csv', encoding="utf8") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        f.seek(1)
        listing = []
        for row in reader:
            if row[0] == id: 
                listing.append(row[0])
                listing.append(row[48])
                listing.append(row[49])
                listing.append(amount_of_reviews_2019(id))
        listings.append(listing)
        print(len(listings))

def format_csv(data, lock):
    with lock:
        with open('D:/temp/multiprocessing.csv', 'a+', newline='', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
            filewriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            print(data)
            filewriter.writerows(data)
            #for y in data:
                #filewriter.writerow([y[0], y[1], y[2], y[3]])


def do(counter, lock):
    for id in idList:
        if counter.value < len(idList): #len(idList) = 20245 #When i put lets say 15 here I get all 15 expected results
            with counter.get_lock():
                counter.value += 1 #I am aware I skip the 0 index here
                print(counter.value)
            calc(idList[counter.value])
        else:
            format_csv(listings, lock)
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    print(len(idList))
    sharedCounter = Value('i', 0)

    processes = []
    for i in range(os.cpu_count()):
        print('registering process %d' % i)
        processes.append(Process(target=do, args=(sharedCounter, lock)))

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    print (datetime.datetime.now())
```

Comment: 20K rows is a very small number of rows. It may not even fill the CPU's cache.  The cost of cross-process communication alone should negate any benefits. Even with multithreading, the cost may be higher than any benefits

Comment: amount_of_reviews works with a 180mb CSV that it has to run through a lot of times. len(idList) = 20245. Currently it takes around 4h to run. 20+ without multiprocessing

Comment: In that case, update the question and add all the relevant information. Don't force people to read the entire code to understand what's going on. In this case though, you could just load the data into a database, index it and start crunching.

Comment: In general, *data* parallelism works by splitting the data into partitions and having a worker crunch a single partition each time. No need for locking or synchronization in this case. CSVs can be easily partitioned along lines. When all the workers finish, a single process can collect their results.

Comment: BTW that's how map/reduce works: one step splits the inputs and maps them to workers, another collects the results produces the final output.

Comment: Thanks for informing me about this. Would you mind having a quick look at: https://www.machinelearningplus.com/python/parallel-processing-python/ I would like to be sure this is what you're telling me

Comment: _I am using multiprocessing to reduce the time the program takes to run_ Here’s the thing. Putting aside the details of this particular implementation for a second, do you know for a fact that multiprocessing is a necessity, and that it will improve performance? Have you done any benchmarking/profiling? Overall, I think @PanagiotisKanavos makes some excellent points.

Comment: It would be great if you could share the data with us. I could do some benchmarking and try to write a solution tomorrow. I obviously haven’t given your code an in-depth look yet, but I would be unhappy if I can’t get it down to under 5 seconds.

Comment: @Alexander Cécile yes it makes all the difference because of the file sizes and amount_of_reviews method. I will look into data parallelism and parallel processing and give it a shot!

Comment: @Alexander Cécile http://insideairbnb.com/get-the-data.html is where you can download the data. The CSV's I use are listings.csv and reviews.csv. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @imagine93 Alright, but what leads you to say that?

Comment: @Alexander Cécile I tried to run it with and without and write text to the terminal about the progression. Also CPU usage is at 100% when multiprocessing and +-10 without. Without multiprocessing 20hrs wasn't enough time to finish on my system (Ryzen 5 2600) this finishes in 4/5

Comment: @imagine93 20 hours!? How big are the input files? Can you explain the functioning of the program?

Comment: Calculate the total of reviews for each review from 2019 (from reviews.csv, 180mb) for each unique listing id (listings.csv, +- 20mb)

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot faster if you used numpy for example to change the csv's to arrays and do your counting with those?

Comment: @imagine93 Do you use the gzipped versions of the files, or the uncompressed ones? Only the Amsterdam data?

Comment: Also, if an ID has no reviews, it should still show up in the result, right? The count could be NaN or 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Diagnosis

Without having given it an in-depth look, I would say there are two main culprits here, and they both go hand-in-hand:

First, there's the repeated file parsing and iteration. You iterate over every ID in the "main loop", so 20,025 times. For each ID, you then read and iterate over the **entire** listings file (20,051 lines), and the **entire** reviews file (493,816 lines). That adds up to reading a cool 10 billion 290 million 186 thousand 675 lines of CSV.

Second, there's the multiprocessing itself. I haven't given it an in-depth look, but I think it's fair to say that we can get a good idea of the problem just from the code. As we saw above, for each ID your program opens both CSV files. Having a bunch of processes which all need to write to the same two files, 20,000 times in total, can't be good for performance. I wouldn't be entirely surprised if the code ran faster without the multiprocessing than with it. There's also the potential race condition mentioned by Daniel Junglas.

---

### Solutions

#### 1.

Alright, it's still a mess, but I just wanted to get something out there before the turn of the century. I will keep searching for a better solution. Based on the number of listings which appear in reviews but not in `listings.csv`, amongst other things, the ideal solution might be slightly different.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

listings_df = pd.read_csv('../resources/listings.csv', header=0, usecols=['id'], dtype={'id': str})

reviews_df = pd.read_csv('../resources/reviews.csv', header=0, parse_dates=['date'], dtype={'listing_id': str})

valid_reviews = reviews_df[reviews_df['date'] >= pd.Timestamp(year=2019, month=1, day=1)]

review_id_counts = valid_reviews['listing_id'].value_counts()

counts_res: pd.DataFrame = pd.merge(listings_df, review_id_counts, left_on='id', right_index=True, how='left').rename(columns={'listing_id': 'review_count'})
counts_res['review_count'] = counts_res['review_count'].fillna(0).astype(np.int64)

counts_res.to_csv(path_or_buf='../out/listing_review_counts.csv', index=False)
```

Runtime is around 1s, which means I did beat my target of 5 seconds or less. Yay :)

#### 2.

This method uses a dictionary to count reviews, and the standard csv module. Bear in mind that it will throw an error if a review is for a listing which is not in `listings.csv`.

```py
import csv
import datetime

with open('../resources/listings.csv') as listings_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(listings_file)
    listing_review_counts = dict.fromkeys((row['id'] for row in reader), 0)

cutoff_date = datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)

with open('../resources/reviews.csv') as reviews_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(reviews_file)
    for row in reader:
        rev_date = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(row['date']).date()
        if rev_date >= cutoff_date:
            listing_review_counts[row['listing_id']] += 1

with open('../out/listing_review_counts_2.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerow(('id', 'review_count'))
    writer.writerows(listing_review_counts.items())
```

#### 3.

This method uses [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and the standard csv module.

```py
import collections as colls
import csv
import datetime

cutoff_date = datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)

with open('../resources/reviews.csv') as reviews_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(reviews_file)
    review_listing_counts = colls.Counter(
        (row['listing_id'] for row in reader if datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(row['date']).date() >= cutoff_date))

with open('../resources/listings.csv') as listings_file, open('../out/listing_review_counts_3.csv', 'w',
                                                              newline='') as out_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(listings_file)
    listings_ids = (row['id'] for row in reader)

    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerow(('id', 'review_count'))
    writer.writerows(((curr_id, review_listing_counts[curr_id]) for curr_id in listings_ids))
```

---

Let me know if you have any questions, if I should include some explanations, etc. :)

Comment: Soory for the late reply. Thank you so much. This makes all the difference. Which method would you normally prefer to use when doing something like this? I knew my program was inefficient but you really showed me how bad it was and why. I will be trying to use numpy and pandas more in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: @imagine93 It really depends on the rest of the program. Pandas is great for any number of complex operations, and has no major downsides compared to the others, so I would probably go for that.

Answer (score 2):

This code looks like it has a race condition:

```
    with counter.get_lock():
        counter.value += 1 #I am aware I skip the 0 index here
        print(counter.value)
    calc(idList[counter.value])
```

You increment the `counter` while holding a lock on it, fine. However, then in `idList[counter.value]` you query the value of the counter **outside** the lock. So another thread/process may have changed the counter in the meantime. In that case you will read an unexpected value from the counter. A safe way to write your code would be this:

```
    value = None
    with counter.get_lock():
        counter.value += 1 #I am aware I skip the 0 index here
        value = counter
    print(value)
    calc(idList[value])
```

**EDIT** Here is a version of your code that has all race conditions removed (I believe) and also has the file I/O removed. It works correctly for me. Maybe you can add back the file I/O piece by piece and see where things go wrong

```
import csv
import os
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Array, Value
import datetime

print (datetime.datetime.now())

idSet = set(range(20245))
idList = list(idSet)
idList = sorted(idList)
listings = []

totalCounter = Value('i', 0)

def calc(id):
    listing = []
    listings.append(listing)

def format_csv(data, lock):
    with lock:
        totalCounter.value += len(data)

def do(counter, lock):
    for id in idList:
        value = None
        with counter.get_lock():
            if counter.value < len(idList):
                value = counter.value
                counter.value += 1
        if value is not None:
            calc(idList[value])
        else:
            format_csv(listings, lock)
            break

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()

    sharedCounter = Value('i', 0)

    processes = []
    for i in range(os.cpu_count()):
        processes.append(Process(target=do, args=(sharedCounter, lock)))

    for process in processes:
        process.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    print (datetime.datetime.now())
    print('len(idList): %d, total: %d' % (len(idList), totalCounter.value))
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I will make this change and let it run overnight to test if this solved my initial problem. Thanks for your time

Comment: This change made sense but didn't help solving the issue. I still got less (18589) rows returned instead of the expected 20245 (len(idList))

Comment: Two things: 1. To simplify debugging you can check whether `calc` is invoked for each `id`. You don't actually have to execute the code in `calc`. As far as I can tell, the function will *always* add exactly one element to `listings`. If the function is not invoked for each `id` or if there is an invocation for which it does not add an element then you can backtrack from there. 2. The test `counter.value < len(idList)` should be inside the lock as well. Also this `for id in idList` in function `do()` looks a bit fishy to me. You can try `while True` and break if `counter.value == len`.

Comment: I have edited my answer to show what I think is a correct code that is as close as possible to your original code.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using pandas to read the files (thanks Alexander). and then loop through the listings and sum all reviews that have that specific id and are after 2019 :

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import datetime
import time

listing_csv_filename = r'listings.csv'
reviews_csv_filename = r'reviews.csv'
start = time.time()
df_listing = pandas.read_csv(listing_csv_filename, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
df_reviews = pandas.read_csv(reviews_csv_filename, delimiter=',', parse_dates=[1])
values = list()
valid_year = df_reviews['date'] > datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
for id_num in df_listing['id']:
    valid = (df_reviews['listing_id'] == id_num) & valid_year
    values.append((id_num, np.sum(valid)))

print(values)
print(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: A few tips: you can have those two `open()` in a single with statement. Instead of calling `readlines()` and the interating, just iterate over the file object itself. It should save time and memory. There is probably no disadvantage, and even an advantage, to making all those `.replace()` without checking whether the substring is contained in the string. Why not just use Pandas for this? I haven’t seen the CSV yet, but unless it’s extremely screwed up `read_csv()` should be fine, no?

Comment: Thanks for that, pandas readcsv seems to be a lot more robust.